# How to display a text on mouseHover event on a QGraphicsPathItem in PyQt5?

Tags: pyqt5, qgraphicspathitem

I am trying to show a connection by a line (using QGraphicsPathItem) and display a text when I mouse hover on that line.
However, I am not able to bring up a text during mouse hover on the line.
A basic working version of the application code is below.
Inside, class Edge, I have written a hoverEnterEvent which is working when I mouse hover on the line. Not sure, how to display the text on it.
Any help on showing the text on mouse hover will be very nice.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QGraphicsView

class NodeEditorWnd(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setGeometry(200, 200, 800, 600)

        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

        # crate graphics scene
        self.scene = MyScene()
        # self.grScene = self.scene.grScene

        self.addNodes()

        # create graphics view
        #self.view = QDMGraphicsView(self.scene.grScene, self)
        self.view = MyView(self.scene)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.view)


        self.setWindowTitle("Node Editor")
        self.show()

    def addNodes(self):
        node1 = Node(self.scene, "My Awesome Node 1", inputs=[1,2,3], outputs=[1])
        node2 = Node(self.scene, "My Awesome Node 2", inputs=[1,2,3], outputs=[1])
        print ("This is addNodes..")
        node1.setPos(-350, -250)
        node2.setPos(-75, 0)

        edge1 = Edge(self.scene, 100, 500)
        self.scene.addItem(edge1)
        
class NodeContent(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

        self.wdg_label = QLabel("Some Title")
        self.layout.addWidget(self.wdg_label)
        self.layout.addWidget(QTextEdit("foo"))


class Node(QGraphicsItem):
    def __init__(self, scene_ref, title="MyNode", inputs=[], outputs=[], parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.scene_ref = scene_ref

        self._title_color = Qt.white
        self._title_font = QFont("Ubuntu", 10)

        self.width = 180
        self.height = 240
        self.edge_size = 10.0
        self.title_height = 24.0
        self._padding = 4.0
        self._pen_default = QPen(QColor("#7F000000"))
        self._pen_selected = QPen(QColor("#FFFFA637"))

        self._brush_title = QBrush(QColor("#FF313131"))
        self._brush_background = QBrush(QColor("#E3212121"))

        self.content = NodeContent()

        self.initTitle()
        self.title = title
        self.initContent()
        self.initUI()
        self.scene_ref.addNode(self)
        self.scene_ref.addItem(self)


    def boundingRect(self):
        return QRectF(
            0,
            0,
            2 * self.edge_size + self.width,
            2 * self.edge_size + self.height
        ).normalized()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable)
        self.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable)


    def initTitle(self):
        self.title_item = QGraphicsTextItem(self)
        self.title_item.setDefaultTextColor(self._title_color)
        self.title_item.setFont(self._title_font)
        self.title_item.setPos(self._padding, 0)
        self.title_item.setTextWidth(
            self.width
            - 2 * self._padding
        )

    @property
    def title(self): return self._title
    @title.setter
    def title(self, value):
        self._title = value
        self.title_item.setPlainText(self._title)

    def paint(self, painter, QStyleOptionGraphicsItem, widget=None):
        # title
        path_title = QPainterPath()
        path_title.setFillRule(Qt.WindingFill)
        path_title.addRoundedRect(0,0, self.width, self.title_height, self.edge_size, self.edge_size)
        path_title.addRect(0, self.title_height - self.edge_size, self.edge_size, self.edge_size)
        path_title.addRect(self.width - self.edge_size, self.title_height - self.edge_size, self.edge_size, self.edge_size)
        painter.setPen(Qt.NoPen)
        painter.setBrush(self._brush_title)
        painter.drawPath(path_title.simplified())

        # content
        path_content = QPainterPath()
        path_content.setFillRule(Qt.WindingFill)
        path_content.addRoundedRect(0, self.title_height, self.width, self.height - self.title_height, self.edge_size, self.edge_size)
        path_content.addRect(0, self.title_height, self.edge_size, self.edge_size)
        path_content.addRect(self.width - self.edge_size, self.title_height, self.edge_size, self.edge_size)
        painter.setPen(Qt.NoPen)
        painter.setBrush(self._brush_background)
        painter.drawPath(path_content.simplified())

    def initContent(self):
        self.grContent = QGraphicsProxyWidget(self)

        self.content.setGeometry(int(self.edge_size), int(self.title_height + self.edge_size), int(self.width - 2*self.edge_size), int(self.height - 2*self.edge_size-self.title_height))
        #self.content.setGeometry(self.edge_size, self.title_height + self.edge_size, self.width - 2*self.edge_size, self.height - 2*self.edge_size-self.title_height)
        self.grContent.setWidget(self.content)

class Edge(QGraphicsPathItem):
    def __init__(self, scene_ref, sp,ep,  parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self._color = QColor("#001000")
        self._color_selected = QColor("#00ff00")
        self._pen = QPen(self._color)
        self._pen_selected = QPen(self._color_selected)
        self._pen.setWidthF(2.0)
        self._pen_selected.setWidthF(2.0)
        self.setAcceptHoverEvents(True)
        self.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable)

        self.setZValue(-1)

        self.posSource = [-170, -190]
        self.posDestination = [100, 100]



    def paint(self, painter, QStyleOptionGraphicsItem, widget=None):
        self.updatePath()

        painter.setPen(self._pen if not self.isSelected() else self._pen_selected)
        painter.setBrush(Qt.NoBrush)
        painter.drawPath(self.path())

    def updatePath(self):
        path = QPainterPath(QPointF(self.posSource[0], self.posSource[1]))
        path.lineTo(self.posDestination[0], self.posDestination[1])
        self.setPath(path)

    def hoverEnterEvent(self, event):
        print ("Inside mouse hover event ------\n")
        color = QColor("red")
        pen = self.pen()
        pen.setColor(color)
        self.setPen(pen)
        QGraphicsItem.hoverMoveEvent(self, event)


class MyScene(QGraphicsScene):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.nodes = []
        self.edges = []

        self.scene_width = 64000
        self.scene_height = 64000
        
        self._color_background = QColor("#0af5d2")
        self.setBackgroundBrush(self._color_background)
        
    def addNode(self, node):
        self.nodes.append(node)
 

class MyView(QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self, scene_ref, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        #self.initUI()
        self.scene_ref = scene_ref
        self.setScene(self.scene_ref)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    wnd = NodeEditorWnd()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Thanks

Comment: You need to create a widget to contain the text. For anything that inherits from Qwidget you can use the Qtooltip, but I'm not sure about QGraphicItems.

Answer (score 0):

I could achieve it by adding

```
QGraphicsItem.setToolTip(self, "100")
```

in the hoverEnterEvent function

Full code below:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QGraphicsView

class NodeEditorWnd(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setGeometry(200, 200, 800, 600)

        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

        # crate graphics scene
        self.scene = MyScene()
        # self.grScene = self.scene.grScene

        self.addNodes()

        # create graphics view
        #self.view = QDMGraphicsView(self.scene.grScene, self)
        self.view = MyView(self.scene)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.view)


        self.setWindowTitle("Node Editor")
        self.show()

    def addNodes(self):
        node1 = Node(self.scene, "My Awesome Node 1", inputs=[1,2,3], outputs=[1])
        node2 = Node(self.scene, "My Awesome Node 2", inputs=[1,2,3], outputs=[1])
        print ("This is addNodes..")
        node1.setPos(-350, -250)
        node2.setPos(-75, 0)

        edge1 = Edge(self.scene, 100, 500)
        self.scene.addItem(edge1)
        
class NodeContent(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

        self.wdg_label = QLabel("Some Title")
        self.layout.addWidget(self.wdg_label)
        self.layout.addWidget(QTextEdit("foo"))


class Node(QGraphicsItem):
    def __init__(self, scene_ref, title="MyNode", inputs=[], outputs=[], parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.scene_ref = scene_ref

        self._title_color = Qt.white
        self._title_font = QFont("Ubuntu", 10)

        self.width = 180
        self.height = 240
        self.edge_size = 10.0
        self.title_height = 24.0
        self._padding = 4.0
        self._pen_default = QPen(QColor("#7F000000"))
        self._pen_selected = QPen(QColor("#FFFFA637"))

        self._brush_title = QBrush(QColor("#FF313131"))
        self._brush_background = QBrush(QColor("#E3212121"))

        self.content = NodeContent()

        self.initTitle()
        self.title = title
        self.initContent()
        self.initUI()
        self.scene_ref.addNode(self)
        self.scene_ref.addItem(self)


    def boundingRect(self):
        return QRectF(
            0,
            0,
            2 * self.edge_size + self.width,
            2 * self.edge_size + self.height
        ).normalized()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable)
        self.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable)


    def initTitle(self):
        self.title_item = QGraphicsTextItem(self)
        self.title_item.setDefaultTextColor(self._title_color)
        self.title_item.setFont(self._title_font)
        self.title_item.setPos(self._padding, 0)
        self.title_item.setTextWidth(
            self.width
            - 2 * self._padding
        )

    @property
    def title(self): return self._title
    @title.setter
    def title(self, value):
        self._title = value
        self.title_item.setPlainText(self._title)

    def paint(self, painter, QStyleOptionGraphicsItem, widget=None):
        # title
        path_title = QPainterPath()
        path_title.setFillRule(Qt.WindingFill)
        path_title.addRoundedRect(0,0, self.width, self.title_height, self.edge_size, self.edge_size)
        path_title.addRect(0, self.title_height - self.edge_size, self.edge_size, self.edge_size)
        path_title.addRect(self.width - self.edge_size, self.title_height - self.edge_size, self.edge_size, self.edge_size)
        painter.setPen(Qt.NoPen)
        painter.setBrush(self._brush_title)
        painter.drawPath(path_title.simplified())

        # content
        path_content = QPainterPath()
        path_content.setFillRule(Qt.WindingFill)
        path_content.addRoundedRect(0, self.title_height, self.width, self.height - self.title_height, self.edge_size, self.edge_size)
        path_content.addRect(0, self.title_height, self.edge_size, self.edge_size)
        path_content.addRect(self.width - self.edge_size, self.title_height, self.edge_size, self.edge_size)
        painter.setPen(Qt.NoPen)
        painter.setBrush(self._brush_background)
        painter.drawPath(path_content.simplified())

    def initContent(self):
        self.grContent = QGraphicsProxyWidget(self)

        self.content.setGeometry(int(self.edge_size), int(self.title_height + self.edge_size), int(self.width - 2*self.edge_size), int(self.height - 2*self.edge_size-self.title_height))
        #self.content.setGeometry(self.edge_size, self.title_height + self.edge_size, self.width - 2*self.edge_size, self.height - 2*self.edge_size-self.title_height)
        self.grContent.setWidget(self.content)

class Edge(QGraphicsPathItem):
    def __init__(self, scene_ref, sp,ep,  parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self._color = QColor("#001000")
        self._color_selected = QColor("#00ff00")
        self._pen = QPen(self._color)
        self._pen_selected = QPen(self._color_selected)
        self._pen.setWidthF(2.0)
        self._pen_selected.setWidthF(2.0)
        self.setAcceptHoverEvents(True)
        self.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable)

        self.setZValue(-1)

        self.posSource = [-170, -190]
        self.posDestination = [100, 100]



    def paint(self, painter, QStyleOptionGraphicsItem, widget=None):
        self.updatePath()

        painter.setPen(self._pen if not self.isSelected() else self._pen_selected)
        painter.setBrush(Qt.NoBrush)
        painter.drawPath(self.path())

    def updatePath(self):
        path = QPainterPath(QPointF(self.posSource[0], self.posSource[1]))
        path.lineTo(self.posDestination[0], self.posDestination[1])
        self.setPath(path)

    def hoverEnterEvent(self, event):
        print ("Inside mouse hover event ------\n")
        color = QColor("red")
        pen = self.pen()
        pen.setColor(color)
        self.setPen(pen)
        QGraphicsItem.hoverMoveEvent(self, event)
        QGraphicsItem.setToolTip(self, "100") 



class MyScene(QGraphicsScene):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.nodes = []
        self.edges = []

        self.scene_width = 64000
        self.scene_height = 64000
        
        self._color_background = QColor("#0af5d2")
        self.setBackgroundBrush(self._color_background)
        
    def addNode(self, node):
        self.nodes.append(node)
 

class MyView(QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self, scene_ref, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        #self.initUI()
        self.scene_ref = scene_ref
        self.setScene(self.scene_ref)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    wnd = NodeEditorWnd()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```